# Is the canonical parameter (and therefore the canonical link function) for a Gamma not unique?

Tags: self-study, generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution, exponential-family

Consider $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ independent from the Gamma distribution. For $y > 0$:
$$\begin{align}
f(y \mid \alpha, \beta) &= \dfrac{1}{\beta^{\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)}y^{\alpha-1}e^{-y/\beta} \\
&= \exp\left[-\log(\beta^{\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha))+(\alpha-1)\log(y)-\dfrac{y}{\beta} \right] \\
&= \exp\left[y\left(\dfrac{-1}{\beta} \right)-\log(\beta^{\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha))+(\alpha-1)\log(y) \right]
\end{align}$$
I define an exponential dispersion family as any distribution whose PMF/PDF is 
$$f(y \mid \boldsymbol\theta) = \exp\left\{\phi[y\theta - b(\theta)] + c(y, \phi) \right\}\text{, } y \in \Omega$$
where $\Omega$ is in the support of a random variable $Y$ in the family.

---

## Method 1:

Therefore, $Y_i$ is of the exponential dispersion family with (assuming $\alpha_i$ is known)
\begin{align}
\phi &= 1 \\
\theta_i &= \dfrac{-1}{\beta_i} \\
b(\theta_i) &= \log[\beta_i^{\alpha_i}\Gamma(\alpha_i)] \\
&= \log[(-\theta_i)^{-\alpha_i}\Gamma(\alpha_i)] \\
&= -\alpha_i\log(-\theta_i) + \log \Gamma(\alpha_i) \\
c(\phi, y_i) &= (\alpha_i-1)\log(y_i)\text{.}
\end{align}
It follows that
\begin{equation}
\mu_i = b^{\prime}(\theta_i) = \dfrac{-\alpha_i}{-\theta_i}(-1) = \dfrac{-\alpha_i}{\theta_i}\text{.}
\end{equation}
and our canonical link is

$$g(\mu_i) = \theta_i = -\dfrac{\alpha_i}{\mu_i}\tag{*}$$

---

## Method 2:

Credit due to http://civil.colorado.edu/~balajir/CVEN6833/lectures/GammaGLM-01.pdf.

Let $\theta = -\dfrac{1}{\alpha\beta}$. Then rewrite
$$\begin{align}f(y \mid \alpha, \beta) &= \exp\left[y\left(\dfrac{-1}{\beta} \right)-\log(\beta^{\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha))+(\alpha-1)\log(y) \right] \\
&= \exp\left[y\left(\dfrac{-1}{\beta} \right)-\alpha\log(\beta)-\log\Gamma(\alpha)+(\alpha-1)\log(y) \right] \\
&= \exp\left[y\alpha\theta-\alpha\log(\theta^{-1})-\log\Gamma(\alpha)+(\alpha-1)\log(y) \right] \\
&= \exp\left\{\alpha[y\theta-\log(\theta^{-1})]-\log\Gamma(\alpha)+(\alpha-1)\log(y) \right\} 
\end{align}$$
in which case, since $\phi$ cannot vary depending on $i$,
\begin{align}
\phi &= \alpha \\
\theta_i &= -\dfrac{1}{\alpha\beta_i} \\
b(\theta_i) &= \log(\theta_i^{-1}) = -\log(\theta_i)\\
c(\phi, y_i) &= (\alpha-1)\log(y_i)-\log\Gamma(\alpha)\text{.}
\end{align}
In this case, $b^{\prime}(\theta_i) =-\dfrac{1}{\theta_i} = \mu_i$, which means that $$g(\mu_i) = \theta_i = -\dfrac{1}{\mu_i}\text{.}\tag{**}$$

---

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function) cites (**) as the canonical link function. **Why is (**) preferable over (*) for the canonical link function**?

What makes this even more confusing is that http://civil.colorado.edu/~balajir/CVEN6833/lectures/GammaGLM-01.pdf says that the canonical link function is $\dfrac{1}{\mu_i}$ (also mentioned in McCullagh and Nelder).

> **First main question**: Are canonical link functions unique, when provided a random component?
>
> **Second main question**: Is there only supposed to be **one** canonical link function for each random component? If so, what is wrong with the work above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The systematic component of the GLM is 
$$g(\mu_i) = \mathbf{x}_i^{\prime}\boldsymbol\beta\text{.}$$
**As long as we do not place any restrictions on the $\boldsymbol\beta$ coefficients**, without loss of generality, we may ignore all constants (with respect to $\mu_i$) of proportionality (these constants will just be absorbed into $\boldsymbol\beta$). Thus, any of the link functions above will work as a canonical link function, but $g(\mu_i) = \dfrac{1}{\mu_i}$ is the simplest one to work with.